# Firestore - How to setup security rule without Auth, but based on Android client/request data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

In my case, Firestore database looks like below, where each Android client will have one document mapped to his/her device  `Document_sdfljkhsdio  ( specific to Android User 1 )`

```
FireStoreCollection
     Document_sdfljkhsdio  ( specific to Android User 1 ) 
            Collection_xyz 
                  Document_xyz                      
     Document_kjjkssefd  ( specific to Android User 2 ) 
            Collection_xyz 
                  Document_xyz                      
     Document_sqdfwdfsme  ( specific to Android User 3 ) 
            Collection_xyz 
                  Document_xyz
```

I am not implementing Google Auth, but instead want to send document name `Document_sdfljkhsdio` as request data and match it with some rules at Firebase Console

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /document/{document_sent_from_client}/ {
      allow read, write: if request.document_sent_from_client == document_sent_from_client;
    }
  }
}
```

Am not sure if it is possible to send document name from Android device ,if yes, please suggest.

And also suggest if it is the correct approach, suggest if you have any better approach ?

Thanks for your  help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds totally feasible. To pass the `document_sent_from_client` from an Android client, just build a `DocumentReference` with a path to `/document/document_sent_from_client`. Modified from [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document):

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("document").document("document_sent_from_client");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

But the security rules don't help here: if the client requests an existing document (i.e. if they **know** the path to a document), they will get a result. If they request a non-existing document (i.e. if they **don't know** the path to a document), the task will fail.

You're essentially depending on the key in `document_sent_from_client` to be reasonably unguessable. Such "security by obscurity" is fairly common in the absence of an authenticated user.

Comment: thank so much, learned 2 things 1) How to catch client data 2) It must be unguessable, though I am away from testing, and have posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203390/how-to-setup-firestore-security-rules-correctly