# How to setup Firestore security rules correctly

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

Though it looks simple, I am still struggling to setup some basic Firestore rules, which are not working as expected.

For scenarios and queries posted below, this database is used:

[image: Database Screen]

**Scenario 1**

Am not able to figure out database name? I thought it's `restaurants`, but with this assumption, below code didn’t work, and getting `PERMISSION_DENIED` exception:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if database == "restaurants";
    }
  }
}
```

**Scenario 2**

Collection restaurants have 10 documents, as appearing in above screen, I have hard coded those 10, and allowed them to read and write as below, but its not working, and getting same `PERMISSION_DENIED` exception:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {

     allow read : if document in ['2uFMIc2BSH6oslxEABpB','8GMNVxVUb1HzRAk2QmmX',
      'AryyMURod8AeWAfBVavF','AvnpKGMeUWDSfowFLpwa','H0qi7gI8WmSVobu19G49',
      'H2xhfoj0Rn75BH9nnbuI','NRfgppqWRfj3DtHDlft4','R9gZ0hTxCPXwSeV2prNV',
      'YgXXwndeIfZx6rUhdlc4','v22FlL7LBBY851N8sIvQ'] ;

      allow write : if document in ['2uFMIc2BSH6oslxEABpB','8GMNVxVUb1HzRAk2QmmX',
      'AryyMURod8AeWAfBVavF','AvnpKGMeUWDSfowFLpwa','H0qi7gI8WmSVobu19G49',
      'H2xhfoj0Rn75BH9nnbuI','NRfgppqWRfj3DtHDlft4','R9gZ0hTxCPXwSeV2prNV',
      'YgXXwndeIfZx6rUhdlc4','v22FlL7LBBY851N8sIvQ'] ;


    }
  }
}
```

These 2 may not be very practical scenarios, but its more for my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your first example, `database` is the name of your database, which is probably something like "(default)".
2. In your second example, `document` is going to be the full path of your document; that's what that `=**` wildcard does -- it's a "everything else in my path" kind of wildcard. So it'll equal something like `restaurants/2uFMIc2BSH6oslxEABpB`

If you want to create a rule that says, "A user can read any document in my restaurants collection" you want something like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /restaurants/{restaurantID} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to do something interesting with the document ID of your individual restaurants, you probably want to do something more like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /restaurants/{restaurantID} {
      allow read, write: if restaurantID == '2uFMIc2BSH6oslxEABpB; ;
    }
  }
}
```